# Error installing rmagick on Debian Sid

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, debian, rmagick

I had to switch ruby version to 2.0.0-p353. I use rbenv and installed the p353 normally (rbenv install ).

For some reason rmagick failed to install on this ruby version. Full error here:

```
Fetching: rmagick-2.13.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/dot/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find Magick-config in /home/dot/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin:/home/dot/.rbenv/libexec:/home/dot/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/dot/perl5/bin:/home/dot/opt/bin:/home/dot/.rbenv/bin:/home/dot/perl5/bin:/home/dot/.rbenv/shims:/home/dot/opt/bin:/home/dot/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/dot/opt/algs4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/dot/opt/algs4/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/dot/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /home/dot/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/dot/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

**I have all headers and -dev packages installed on my system since rmagick is installed in 2.0.0-p481.**

```
$ rbenv version && gem list | grep rmagick
2.0.0-p481 (set by /home/dot/.rbenv/version)
rmagick (2.13.2)
```

.

```
apt install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev
imagemagick is already the newest version.
libmagickwand-dev is already the newest version.
```

Here is a fresh installation: http://paste.debian.net/hidden/102606b7/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu:

```
▷ dpkg --search Magick-config
libmagickcore-dev: /usr/share/man/man1/Magick-config.1.gz
libmagickcore-dev: /usr/bin/Magick-config
```

That apparently means that you probably need to

```
▷ sudo apt-get install libmagickcore-dev
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `libmagickcore-dev` is also installed. `dpkg --search Magick-config` return `libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16/Magick-config`

Comment: There are some glitches in your environment, AFAIU. Try `export PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH` before installing rmagick. It should help.

Comment: Yup. I saw that after you wrote about `dpkg --search Magick-config`. I don't know how happend since I have rmagick on all versions currently installed on my machine. Thanks mudasobwa